# expdp/impdp connection string

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, impdp, expdp

I am currently trying to copy a schema with the name in lowercase.
So in order to connect via `sqlplus` I simply do:

```
sqlplus \"schema_name\"/schema_pass@localhost/DBRAZRAB
```

That works well.

Of course naively I tried the same approach for `expdp`/`impdp`, but that does not work this time:

```
[oracle@3e7716e807ed ~]$ expdp \"schema_name\"/schema_pass@localhost/DBRAZRAB schemas=\"schema_name\" <...>

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Mar 3 13:44:43 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Password:
```

Could someone please give me a hint, what am I doing  wrong? Which format should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The documentation does mention that quotation marks can be an issue with calling expdp/impdp, and [recommends using a PARFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL859), but that doesn't help with the username issue.

As a workaround, you could run the export as SYSTEM (or similar user with DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE privilege):

```
sqlplus SYSTEM/pass@localhost/DBRAZRAB PARFILE=params.txt
```

with a parameter file like:

```
SCHEMAS="schema_name"
DUMPFILE=...etc...
```

Comment: thank you for the hint, a parfile contains only params, hence the username/pass still should be entered. like you correctly mentioned. Regarding using `SYSTEM`: it would be rather a someone's mistake to have available pass for `SYSTEM` on a production system.

Answer (score 0):

After an evening of a research I came up with the following:

Added a user with the privileges `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE`, `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE`;

Configured parfiles and applied them:

**schema_exp.par:**

```
SCHEMAS=\"schema_123\"
DUMPFILE=schema.dmp
DIRECTORY=schema_dir
LOGFILE=schema_exp.log
```

```
[oracle@3e7716e807ed ~]$ expdp expimp_user/expimp_pass@localhost/DBRAZRAB parfile=/schema_exp.par
```

**schema_imp.par:**

```
SCHEMAS=\"schema_123\"
DUMPFILE=schema.dmp
DIRECTORY=schema_dir
LOGFILE=schema_imp.log
REMAP_SCHEMA=\"schema_123\":SCHEMA_123
REMAP_TABLESPACE=\"schema_123\":SCHEMA_123
```

```
[oracle@3e7716e807ed ~]$ impdp expimp_user/expimp_pass@localhost/DBRAZRAB parfile=/schema_imp.par
```